# dust.js makes the possibility of nodejs zero down time when hot deploy?

Tags: node.js, dust.js

As I known, node.js can not be zero downtime if change the source code of javascript and restart to run (hot deployment).
Even there are some solution can restart node.js automatically, but they are not real zero downtime restart.
Just wonder due to dustjs has some basic logical function,
if this can makes node.js (while no big change to controller/logic) can be zero downtime when hot deploy.

Comment: Nope,to change anything that is not a static asset you'll need to kill the nodejs process then restart it.Of course,if you use a cluster or a proxy in front of node,you can kill off process while others are still running.And your problem has nothing to do with Dustjs.This lib isnt magics.

Comment: I do this. I use [`fs.watch()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) to watch for file changes, when the file is updated the template is recompiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `liveswap` which enables you to deploy and restart a new version of an app with zero downtime:

https://medium.com/node-js-javascript/f00ce09abb77
https://www.npmjs.org/package/liveswap

usage is pretty straightforward, a bit like [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever)

```
liveswap --start index.js

liveswap —-upgrade index.js
```